# Lower bound on singular values of a bordered matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, singular-values

Let

$M = J + H = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & \vec{1}^{\intercal}\\
\vec{1} & K + \gamma^{-1}I
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & \vec{1}^{\intercal}\\
\vec{1} & 0 
\end{bmatrix}_J + 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0\\
0 &  K + \gamma^{-1}I
\end{bmatrix}_{H}
$

where $\vec{1}$ is a vector of $n$ ones, $K$ is a $N \times N$ symmetric matrix, $\gamma > 0$ and $I$ is the identity.

Is there a lower bound on the singular values of M?

I noticed that the singular values of M are close to the ones of H but I cannot demonstrate it.